# Why can't synchronous actions in Reflux also be used as promises?

Tags: javascript, refluxjs

In my code, I use the [async actions as promises](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs#asynchronous-actions-as-promises) pattern heavily. Here's an example:

```
var actions = Reflux.createActions({connectToFacebook: {asyncResult: true}});

actions.connectToFacebook.listenAndPromise(function(){

    var facebookOauthPromise = _doFacebookConnect(); // implementation elided

    return facebookOauthPromise.then(function(token){
        return $.post('/api/facebook/connect', {token: token});
    });
});

var promise = actions.connectToFacebook();
promise.then(function(){
    // do something on success
});
```

This works great. When first the oAuth and then the POST request completes, `connectToFacebook.completed`, and my outer `promise.then` are fired as expected.

However, I had to add `{sync: true}` to the definition of the action because the implementation of `_doFacebookConnect` calls `window.open`, which will be blocked unless called on the same call stack as a user click event. Reflux by default will use `_.nextTick` when dispatching the event, so it's no longer on the same stack.

When I do this, the action still works properly, and the pop-up blocker is no longer a problem. However, my outer `promise.then` fails to execute, because the return value of `actions.connectToFacebook()` is now `undefined` instead of the promise I returned from `listenAndPromise`.

Why does Reflux suddenly stop passing through the returned promise, and is there any way to elegantly work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way to hack around it, by overriding `action.trigger` rather than using `action.listenAndPromise()`:

```
actions.connectToFacebook.trigger = function(){

    var facebookOauthPromise = _doFacebookConnect(); // implementation elided

    var promise = facebookOauthPromise.then(function(token){
        return $.post('/api/facebook/connect', {token: token});
    });

    this.promise(promise);
    return promise;
};
```

It does seem to cover both dispatching `connectToFacebook.completed` (because of the `this.promise()` call and returning the promise (by explicitly doing so).

However, I'm still not clear on why Reflux doesn't do this automatically.